# Run a PHP function before submit is made using WordPress submit_button()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating an options page in WordPress admin interface. How can I run a PHP function before a submit is made?

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Author</h2>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields('author_option_group'); ?>
    <h4>Author Settings</h4>
    <label for="author">Author: </label>
    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" value="<?php echo get_option('author'); ?>" />
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

The `submit_button()` above is a wordpress function that generates a submit button that saves the input field to the wp options table in the database. I would like to run a function before the submit is run. The function will do some custom validation etc and maybe throw an error and not run the submit if certain conditions are met.

Regardless of what that function will do, how can I supply a function to be run, which determines if the submit will go through or not?

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). The for attribute has to reference another element by its **id**, not name.

Comment: You're right. But it hasn't anything to do with my problem. But I edited it.

Comment: @RyanVincent But this is javascript. I don't want to run a javascript function. I want to run a PHP function before the submit is made.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to validate form in client side so you have to use javascript, if you are using jquery 
it will be like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit',function(){
     // validation
     // if everything is ok return true else return false and show errors

    });
})
```

If you want do validation in server side you have to run your validation before showing form.
You can use wp hook, you can check validation in your `options.php` or you can check it in `functions.php`. With hook it will look like .

```
<?php do_action('before_form_rendered') ?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields('author_option_group'); ?>
    <h4>Author Settings</h4>
    <label for="author">Author: </label>
    <input type="text" id="author" name="author" value="<?php echo get_option('author'); ?>" />
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

and add this code in your `functions.php`

```
add_action('before_form_rendered','validate_author_form');
function validate_author_form(){
    if(isset($_POST['author']) && !empty($_POST['author'])){
       echo 'form has been submited';
    }else{
       echo 'please insert author name';
    }
}
```

Also you can implement your form by ajax.

JS side

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
   $.post('http://yoursite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
           action: 'custom_form', 
           data : $(this).serializeArray()
           },function(response){
            // handle server response here
            console.log(response);
           });
   return false;
});
```

php code add in your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_custom_form', 'custom_form_handler' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_custom_form', 'custom_form_handler' );

// validation goes here
function custom_form_handler(){
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    exit;

}
```

Best Regards,
Davit.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Your first, example, with the hook, is the one that interests me the most. But I would like to run my function (not necessarily validation) before the submit is made. Basically I want this flow: 1) User enters text & clicks "Save". 2) My custom function is run. 3) The submit is made. Can I write a hook that catches "submit_button()"?

Comment: Thank you.

I am so sorry but I don't understand question.
Can you explain me more what is your entire problem maybe there is another more professional and good way to solve it ? Also you can use filters for handling form validation please look wp filters too maybe it will help.

Comment: The validation was just an example. My main question is: When a user clicks the submit button, and the Wordpress function submit_button() is run, is there any way for me to run some function that I have defined BEFORE submit_button() continues with its execution?

Comment: I am sorry but there isn't way.I am sure you are a bit confused it is cycle goes in this way.1) Your client sending request for getting page where you will render form.2) Then in your server run submit_button() function 3) server will generate response and will send html markup to client4) Then client will see form and will submit it in browser.I am sure you want to hook before save( be after client submit,before submit_button() function will be called) and place your code before saving.Look for this hook 'customize_save_after'

Answer (score 1):

i think 2 way can help you.
1. change the input type "submit" 
the file is 
wp-admin\includes\template.php (unction get_submit_button)
2.use preventDefault

```
    onsubmit{
    //docheck
    if(checked){
        //nothing do
    }else{
        alert(wrong);
        e.preventDefault
    }
}
```

but preventDefault IE not support

Comment: But this is javascript. I don't want to run a javascript function. I want to run a PHP function  before the submit is made.